# Do...While... keeps on looping, if else case occurs. C

Tags: c, loops, do-while

The program will run fine as long as there is no error in the input. For eg, If I type "sunday" then the value of d will be set to 1 but if i type some error input say "adfasdf" and after the program loops, it will keep on looping.

This is a part of my menu driven program.

```
            int d,error=0;

            do{
                    char day[100];
                    printf("Enter Day of the Week: ");
                    getchar(); //as gets may accept \n
                    gets(day);
                    strlwr(day);
                    if (strcmp(day,"sunday")==0){
                       d=1;
                       error=1;
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(day,"monday")==0){
                        d=2;
                        error=1;}
                    else if (strcmp(day,"tuesday")==0){
                        d=3;
                        error=1;}
                    else if (strcmp(day,"wednesday")==0){
                        d=4;
                        error=1;}
                    else if (strcmp(day,"thursday")==0){
                        d=5;
                        error=1;}
                    else if (strcmp(day,"friday")==0){
                        d=6;
                        error=1;}
                    else if (strcmp(day,"saturday")==0){
                        d=7;
                        error=1;}
                    else{
                        printf("Invalid Entry!");
                        error=0; //So the program will loop till correct input is placed.
                    }

            }while(error==0);
            printf("%d",d);
            getch();
```

[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObM8J.png)
[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fCB1.png)

Comment: Why are you setting error to 1 for valid input, and 0 for invalid input? That seems backwards.

Comment: What's that `getchar()` for? Explain to your [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

Comment: welcome to SO!  we really hate screenshots of text.  Copy the text and paste it into the question directly, not a screenshot.

Comment: i want to loop the program till the correct input is placed

Comment: @Ughhhh to respond to a particular user's comment, be sure to indicate who you are responding to, as I have done in this comment.

Comment: @jarmod sorry, This is my first time using SO.

Comment: @user3121023 THANKS A LOT FGETS WORKED!!!. How are you supposed to upvote answers?

Comment: You wait until there is an answer and then you upvote it if you have the privilege. Also you select the most helpful one and accept it after a certain time (no privilege needed for that). But there is no answer here.... You could ask the one who answered (@user3121023 ) in a comment why they did not create an answer to make this a useful Q/A pair.

Comment: @Ughhhh no problem, we were all first-timers at some point. Welcome. One thing you should consider changing, however, is `error`. You need to get into good habits early. Having a variable named `error` which behaves exactly opposite to what everyone else would expect is not good coding.

Comment: @Ughhhh please can I know if my answer is useful for you, else I delete it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To use *gets* is dangerous because in case the read line is longer than 99 characters that function writes out of the array with undefined behavior. You do not have that problem using *fgets* but that one reads a *line*, and in fact you want to read a *word*, you do not care about spaces before or after it, in the sense of *isspace* (so also including newline, return, tab, ...), a practical way to do that is to use *scanf*, in the current case `scanf(" %99s", day)`, notice the space before '%' to bypass possible initial spaces.

An other problem is you do not check the result of *gets* (nor *getchar*), so in case of EOF your program loops without ending. So using *scanf* check it return 1 or not.

As said in remark *error* is not a good choice to name your variable, and in fact you do not need it, you can just exit the *for* using *break* when needed, or initialize *d* with 0 and loop while it is 0.

To use *printf* to print a string as it is as you do is expensive and suppose it does not contain '%' etc else the behavior is undefined, use *puts* if you want the trailing newline else *fputs* (check the string is flush).

So for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

/* I do not have strlwr, I define it */
void strlwr(char * s)
{
  while (*s) {
    *s = tolower(*s);
     s += 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int d = 0;
  
  do {
    char day[100];
    
    printf("Enter Day of the Week: ");
    if (scanf(" %99s", day) != 1) {
      puts("read error");
      d = -1; /* or any other action at least exiting the for */
    }
    else {
      strlwr(day);
      
      if (strcmp(day,"sunday")==0)
        d=1;
      else if (strcmp(day,"monday")==0)
        d=2;
      else if (strcmp(day,"tuesday")==0)
        d=3;
      else if (strcmp(day,"wednesday")==0)
        d=4;
      else if (strcmp(day,"thursday")==0)
        d=5;
      else if (strcmp(day,"friday")==0)
        d=6;
      else if (strcmp(day,"saturday")==0)
        d=7;
      else 
        puts("Invalid Entry!");
    }
  } while (d == 0);
  
  if (d != -1)
    printf("%d\n",d);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Enter Day of the Week: today
Invalid Entry!
Enter Day of the Week:     yesterday
Invalid Entry!
Enter Day of the Week:    Monday
2
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo birthday | ./a.out
Enter Day of the Week: Invalid Entry!
Enter Day of the Week: read error
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```